# sync sqlite on ipad with remote sql server

Tags: sql-server, ipad, sqlite, synchronization

I am new to ipad development. I have to develop an app for a client whose employees use ipads.I am to develop this app that would take the data that they have and store it to the main sql server on their server. On researching i came across that people do that once they have their data on ipad and later sync it with their server. I have used sqlite for android before. But that was like a school project. CRUD operations basically. So since i have little knowledge of sqlite i want to pursue this app in this way. My question is can i write an app that will sync temporary sqlite data with server once they sync ? I have more questions..
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly possible to synchronize data between multiple databases.

Generally speaking, you have to record all changes made since the last synchronization (usually done with serial numbers or timestamps), and apply those changes to the other database.

If the same data has been modified by multiple users, you have to resolve this conflict somehow.

If multiple users can add data, you have to prevent duplicates of primary keys.

See these Wikipedia articles for explanations of some related concepts:
[Data synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_synchronization)
[Replication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_%28computing%29)
[Change data capture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture)

Answer (score 0):

this Guy may solve the problem, but it only supports Xamarin(iOS or Android).

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5719/sync-sqlite-with-sql-server-merge-replication